# Was bedeutet »Haste Schiss?«?

Tags: meaning, translation

Seit einigen Jahren lerne ich Deutsch. Ich habe eine Werbung eines Unternehmens gesehen, in der ein Mann im Auto sagt:

> Haste Schiss?

Kann mir bitte jemand sagen, was diese Redewendung bedeutet?

Comment: "haste" is short colloquial for "hast du" and "Schiss" (literally shit) is slang for "Angst". "Haste Schiss?" means "Hast du Angst?"

Comment: @Robert Turn it into an answer.

Comment: Das ist ein Wort, das sich in praktisch jedem ordentlichen Wörterbuch findet. Hast du da schon nachgeschaut?

Comment: @Robert: Die Wortherkunft von *Schiss* wäre eine sinnvolle Ergänzung, die dem OP helfen könnte, den Ausdruck stilistisch einzuordnen.

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Schiss#Noun

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Das Wort *haste* ist eine umgangssprachliche Verkürzung von *hast du*.

Nun zu *Schiss haben*: Als Reaktion auf eine starke angstauslösende Situation kommt es oft zur Entleerung des Darms. Daher sagt man jemandem, der Angst hat, scherzhaft nach: „Er hat die Hosen voll.“ Die Formulierung „Er hat Schiss“ ist eine derbere Variante von „Er hat Angst“, denn sie drückt aus, was sich da in der vollen Hose befindet. [*Schiss*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Schiss) ist ein altes Wort für *Scheiße*.

Comment: "Schiss" kommt auch noch als Teil des Worts "Dünnschiss" (Durchfall) vor.